# Implement search from inside layout in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating my first web app using asp.net core mvc, so I'm stuck with implementing global search using textbox inside layout, I can't find where to implement the search after user press Enter, Is it implemented in controller or something else, and how to implement it...

Comment: Hi @xamo, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm stuck with implementing global search using textbox inside layout, I can't find where to implement the search after user press Enter

To implement the above requirement, you can refer to the following code snippet.

*Adding form with input for searching functionality in `_Layout.cshtml`*

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <form id="f_search" method="get" asp-action="Search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="ipt_search" type="search" class="form-control" name="SearchTerm" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default">
                                Search
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*JS code of checking keydown event and user input*

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#f_search input').keydown(function (e) {

            var searchTerm = $("#ipt_search").val();

            if (searchTerm == "" && event.keyCode === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

*Action method of `Search`*

```
public IActionResult Search(string SearchTerm)
{
    //...
    //do query based on SearchTerm

    //code logic here
    //...

    return View();
}
```

Test Result

[image]